# Android: как перехватить StackTrace от обработанного (!) NoSuchMethod-исключения, случившегося в "чужом" приложении?

Tags: android, отладка, jni, reverse-engineering, ddms

Есть чужое приложение. Я его патчу, беру из него нативную библиотеку и через NativeActivity подгружаю в своем приложении, чтобы чужое приложение как бы запустилось "в контексте моего" и я мог кое-что изменить. Исходников нет, разве что декомпилированные нерабочие. Конечно же, вылетает, ведь в моей NativeActivity и вообще в моей сборке нету классов и методов, которые есть в оригинале и к котором обращается библиотека через JNI. И с каждой версией библиотеки, их всё больше и больше.
Моя задача - плавно, от старых версий к новым, сделать так, чтобы в итоге все необходимое было и приложение хотя бы не слетало при запуске.

Сначала в LogCat обнаруживались исключения NoSuchMethod от JNI. Туда шел полный StackTrace, с полным путем к методу, так что каждое исключение не составляло труда исправить, просто-напросто прилепив "заглушку".
Но в очередной раз вместо StackTrace вижу такое:

```
Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;)

Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;)

Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;)

JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1

VM aborting
```

Что бы это значило (почему нет StackTrace, почему теперь пишет stale ведь в старых версиях работало)? И как все-таки перехватить подробную информацию?

Есть какой-нибудь отладчик на манер "глобального сниффера" всех исключений, что происходят в системе или конкретном приложении?

Comment: я надеюсь ,что это невозможно. Ваша деятельность вообще граничит с нарушением авторских прав.

Comment: @metalurgus теоретически все возможно, почему бы под рутом не пропатчить саму ОС? Тем более, она ж опенсорсная. Но на практике, видимо, никто еще так не сделал.

Comment: @metalurgus разобрался. Всё там возможно. См. ответ. А вам бы, ИМХО,  поучиться да опыта поднабраться, прежде чем права отстаивать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.
Всё просто - по умолчанию приложения Android в Eclipse запускаются без отладки, поэтому кроме LogCat у нас собственно ничего и нет.
Но если жать Debug вместо Run, то будет отладка, где мы сможем проследить всю Stack trace и в том числе докопаться до detailMessage.
Что я и сделал, добавив недостающие методы и исправив все 3 экскепшна.
Но вот "jni error" от этого не исчез, видимо, это отдельная проблема. А с библиотеками JNI гораздо хуже ситуация обстоит - они же в машинном коде, поэтому отладка вообще затруднена. Пока я только узнал, какой метод JNI приводит к ошибке (убрал вызов - нет ошибки). Но это ни о чем пока не говорит.